# Where to find jasperreports-javaflow-3.7.4.jar source code?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I searched in sourceforge.net and in google to get the source code of jasperreports-javaflow-3.7.4 version but couldn't find it. Where can i get the link to download the source file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be here: [jasperreports-3.7.4-project.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/archive/jasperreports/JasperReports%203.7.4/jasperreports-3.7.4-project.tar.gz/download)

Comment: here we find the .class files not java files. The src folder contains .java files which can be compiled for the jasperreports-3.7.4.jar but not for jasperreports-javaflow-3.7.4 ? :( We have a folder javaflow in build folder which contains .class files

Comment: To build the javaflow jar file you need to run the "javaflow" target (see build.xml).